# Prove that $\left \| T \right \|=1$?

Tags: integration, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $E=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ be equipped with $\left \| f \right \|_1=\int_{0}^{1}\left | f(t) \right |dt$ .

Let $T:(E,\left \| . \right \|_1)\rightarrow (E,\left \| . \right \|_1) $ be defined by $T(f)(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$, $\forall f\in E,\forall x\in [0,1]$

I was able to prove that $\left \| T(f) \right \|_1\leq \left \| f \right \|_1$, then:

$\frac{\left \| T(f) \right \|_1}{\left \| f \right \|_1}\leq 1\Rightarrow \underset{x\in [0,1]}{sup}(\frac{\left \| T(f) \right \|_1}{\left \| f \right \|_1})\leq 1\Leftrightarrow \left \| T \right \|\leq 1$

Now in the exercise, they gave a hint for us to use the function, $f_n(x)=(1-x)^n$

I calculated $\frac{\left \| T(f_n) \right \|_1}{\left \| f_n \right \|_1}$, I got $\frac{n+1}{n+2}$, then:$\left \| T \right \|=\frac{n+1}{n+2}$

The problem is that $\frac{n+1}{n+2}\ngeqslant 1$, then it's impossible to have $\left \| T \right \|=1$

Is there something wrong with my results ? Or maybe there is a problem in the question ?

Comment: Let $n \to \infty$ and conclude..

Comment: Do we have the right to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll give you a hint. Suppose that $\Vert T \Vert < 1$ and choose a big $n$.

Comment: You mean by contradiction, for big n we get the norm equal 1 ?

Comment: @PedroAlvarès if $\Vert T \Vert = 1-\varepsilon$ then choose a big $n$ so that $\Vert T\Vert \geq \frac{n+1}{n+2} > 1-\varepsilon$, and obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I found one of the functions that satisfies the given conditions. Let $f_{0}(x)=e^{-nx}$.

Then

$$\frac{||\varphi(f_{0})||_{1} }{||f_{0}||_{1}} = \frac{1+\frac{e^{-n}}{n}-\frac{1}{n}}{1-\frac{e^{-n}}{n}}\rightarrow 1,\quad as \ n \rightarrow +\infty$$

And since $|||\varphi|||$ is bounded by $1$, $sup_{f \in E}(\frac{||\varphi(f)||_{1} }{||f||_{1}}) = 1$.

i.e, $|||\varphi||| = 1$.